# Associate Protractor tests to TFS properly

Tags: mstest, tfs, mtm, protractor

I'm trying to write a few tests in Protractor, but looking a bit forward I wonder if anyone knows how to fully associate my Protractor tests to my test cases in TFS. So, I can run it those tests from  my test cases on Microsoft Test Manager.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can only associate and execute MSTest based test automation to test cases in TFS.  You could write a MSTest test method to wrap each of your protractor test cases.  Somebody did something similar [here](http://www.ranorex.com/blog/running-ranorex-automated-tests-using-microsoft-test-manager) for Ranorex tests.  Doing that manually would be painful, so I'd recommend automating the MSTest dll creation.

There's also the potential to associate your protractor tests directly with TFS Test Cases using something like [this](https://github.com/JakeGinnivan/TestCaseAutomationAssigner).  However, I'm not sure how you would execute them via MTM.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TFS SDK to directly insert test results.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505812/how-to-create-a-test-run-and-result-using-the-team-foundation-server-api.

This may or may not be a worthwhile use of your time to implement something like this.  TFS is pretty integrated with MSTest and the entire Microsoft infrastructure.  While you could use the TFS SDK, it would be much much simpler to use a different TCM that supported results from protractor out of the box.  Is there anything tying you to TFS?

Comment: Is there a TCM for Protractor that allows to see results and test cases in a UI? I haven't found any.